# Negative lookbehind assertion in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a set of file-paths, and I want to list all file-paths that do not contain `x/y/z/`. The other constraint is that I cannot use `print if !m{x/y/z/}` since I don't have write permissions on the script. I can provide the script with regexp patterns to *include* (as command-line-options), i.e., everything that matches will be printed.

This is my attempt. I am trying to match all lines that *do not* have `x/y/z/` before them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
   print if m{(?<!x/y/z/).*};
}

__DATA__
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/a/b/m.cc
x/y/a/b/m.cc
```

My expectation is it would print only the bottom two strings, but it prints everything. But when I change the pattern to `(?<=x/y/z/).*`, it is printing only the top 3 strings:

```
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
```

Why so, and what should I do to fix my regexp?

Comment: `m{(?<!x/y/z/).*}` matches `x/y/z/a/b/x.cc` because `m{(?<!x/y/z/).*}` matches `/y/z/a/b/x.cc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a **negative lookahead**. So, straight from [**the monastery**](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=588318) comes the answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
   print if m{^(?!(?s:.*)x/y/z)}; 
}

__DATA__
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/z/a/b/x.cc
x/y/a/b/m.cc
x/y/a/b/m.cc
```

Comment: literal translation: match a string that does *not* start with any number of any characters followed by `x/y/z`

Comment: Did you really mean to filter out `x/y/zoo/a.cc`? `/` or `(?:/|\z)` needs to be added.

Comment: No, I don't want to filter out `x/y/zoo`. Everything under `x/y/z/` should be filtered. Let me edit the question appropriately.